Keycloak 24 - Why are there so many LOGIN events and KeycloakSessions instances created for a simple user login form
Keycloak 24.0.3
I am developing a custom Service Provider Interface (SPI) for Keycloak and I'm encountering issues understanding the lifecycle of EventListenerProvider and the KeycloakSession session. Specifically, I am puzzled by the number of LOGIN events and the creation of multiple Keycloak sessions during a simple user login process.
Context
My custom SPI implementation involves an EventListenerProviderFactory and an EventListenerProvider. The factory is responsible for creating instances of the provider, which listens for login events. I have implemented logging to trace the creation and handling of these events.
Despite expecting a straightforward sequence of events during user login, the logs indicate that multiple LOGIN events and sessions are created, leading to confusion about the actual lifecycle and behavior of these components.
Key Points of Confusion
Lifecycle of EventListenerProvider: Understanding when and how instances are created and managed.
Keycloak Sessions: Clarifying why multiple sessions are instantiated during a single login event.
Event Handling: Determining if the multiple LOGIN events are expected behavior or indicative of an issue in my implementation.
public class UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory implements EventListenerProviderFactory, ServerInfoAwareProviderFactory {

    @Override
    public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        logger.debug("Factory::create");
        logger.debug("Factory::this : " + this);
        logger.debug("Factory::keycloakSession : " + keycloakSession);
        return new UpdateOnLoginListenerProvider(keycloakSession);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope scope) {
        logger.debug("EventListenerProviderFactory::init");
    }

}

public class UpdateOnLoginListenerProvider implements EventListenerProvider {

    public UpdateOnLoginListenerProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
        logger.debug("Listener::new");
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        var eventType = event.getType();
        logger.debug("Listener::onEvent : " + eventType);
    }

}

Here is my log output
12:54:53,880  (executor-thread-3) Factory::create
12:54:53,880  (executor-thread-3) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:54:53,880  (executor-thread-3) Factory::keycloakSession : session @ 638ed0ac
12:54:53,881 executor-thread-3) Listener::new
12:55:09,165  (executor-thread-7) Factory::create
12:55:09,165  (executor-thread-7) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:55:09,166  (executor-thread-7) Factory::keycloakSession : session @ 09914467
12:55:09,166 executor-thread-7) Listener::new
12:55:09,434 executor-thread-7) Listener::onEvent : LOGIN
12:55:09,444  (executor-thread-7) Factory::create
12:55:09,444  (executor-thread-7) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:55:09,445  (executor-thread-7) Factory::keycloakSession : session @ 135eaa74
12:55:09,445 executor-thread-7) Listener::new
12:55:09,664  (executor-thread-7) Factory::create
12:55:09,664  (executor-thread-7) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:55:09,664  (executor-thread-7) Factory::keycloakSession : session @ 79c40d16
12:55:09,665 executor-thread-7) Listener::new
12:55:09,691  (executor-thread-7) Factory::create
12:55:09,692  (executor-thread-7) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:55:09,692  (executor-thread-7) Factory::keycloakSession : session @ 27563f3d
12:55:09,692 executor-thread-7) Listener::new
12:55:09,709  (executor-thread-7) Factory::create
12:55:09,709  (executor-thread-7) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:55:09,710  (executor-thread-7) Factory::keycloakSession : session @ 2b1a9dcf
12:55:09,710 executor-thread-7) Listener::new
12:55:09,731  (executor-thread-7) Factory::create
12:55:09,731  (executor-thread-7) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:55:09,731  (executor-thread-7) Factory::keycloakSession : session @ 4e2625ba
12:55:09,732 executor-thread-7) Listener::new
12:55:09,749  (executor-thread-7) Factory::create
12:55:09,750  (executor-thread-7) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:55:09,750  (executor-thread-7) Factory::keycloakSession : session @ 231cb923
12:55:09,750 executor-thread-7) Listener::new
12:55:09,759 executor-thread-7) Listener::onEvent : LOGIN
12:55:09,771  (executor-thread-7) Factory::create
12:55:09,772  (executor-thread-7) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:55:09,772  (executor-thread-7) Factory::keycloakSession : session @ 17b2f90d
12:55:09,772 executor-thread-7) Listener::new
12:55:09,974  (executor-thread-3) Factory::create
12:55:09,974  (executor-thread-3) Factory::this : com.spi.UpdateOnLoginListenerProviderFactory@230361e7
12:55:09,974  (executor-thread-3) Factory::keycloakSession :

